# Set a certain bit to a 1 matlab

Tags: matlab, byte, bit

I want to set a certain bit of my configuration header to a 1 (bit 3 of Byte 10) if its not already a 1. And then I want to save this new config header as my old one. I can set the bit ok, however I'm having difficulty replacing the old byte with my new to update my configuration header. I want my new configuration header to be ConfigHeader = [128;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;30];. I know it's probably a very simple solution!!

```
ConfigHeader = [128;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;26];
ByteTen = ConfigHeader(11);
if bitget(ByteTen,3) == 0
% Set bit 3 of byte 10 to 1
bitset(ByteTen,3);

% Replace old config header with new one (bit changed to 1)
ConfigHeader = ??????
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to assign the modified value back to ConfigHeader, e.g. by adding this line:

```
ConfigHeader(11) = bitset(ByteTen,3);
```

This line:

```
bitset(ByteTen,3);
```

on it's own does nothing as long as you don't use its output.

Answer (score 1):

I am not used to bit operations, but juding from your code the next logical step would be:

```
ConfigHeader(11) = ByteTen
```

Perhaps your entire code can even be reduced to:

```
bitset(ConfigHeader(11),3)
```

After all, a bit can only be zero or one so you don't need to test it if you always want to end with a one.